# Is inserted value of pointer type by operator[] in map always NULL?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, initialization, stdmap

What is the expected behaviour for the following code,

```
#include <map>
...
std::map<int, A *> myMap;
myMap[0];
if(myMap[0] == NULL) {// true or false?
}
```

will the if statement evaluate to true?

Comment: `NULL` should read `nullptr` perhaps? Also why not use smart pointers

Comment: That code does nothing as it doesn't compile.  Throw in the correct headers, as `map` could be someone's home made map.

Comment: @EdHeal, its some legacy code in company and we are using legacy compiler.. xD

Comment: If you want to avoid entering invalid numbers into the map, use `find()` for searching, and `insert()` instead of `[]` for making new entry.

Comment: @SauravSahu, I agree with that. it will improve the robustness of the code, but due to very poor SE practice in office, I am not allowed to change code that doesn't belong to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inserted value will be initialized to a null pointer.

[std::map::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will perform an insertion if key does not exist; the mapped value will be [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), for pointer type it's [zero-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), which results in a null pointer.

BTW: Better to use [nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) (since C++11) instead of `NULL`.

Comment: it is due to some constraint that I am working with in my company. we are still using C++98 standard. a lot of features from the latest C++ are missing. e.g smart ptr ... ><

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will accept asap =)